# Python grouping elements in a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a script that counts a how many times the string "small item" appears until it hits the string "large item" and resets then continues. The list consists of `['small item', 'small item', 'large item', 'small item', 'small item']` and I would like it to return [2, 0, 2]

I cannot seem to figure how to do this

Comment: It's right in the name: `itertools.groupby` Though I'm unclear on where the `0` is coming from in your output...

Comment: Are you trying to do this so that it satisfies all possibilities, or just for this scenario?

Comment: all possibilities

Answer (score 0):

```py
items = ['small item', 'small item', 'large item', 'small item', 'small item']

counts = [0]
for item in items:
    if item == 'small item':
        counts[-1] += 1
    else:
        counts.extend((0, 0))

print(counts)
# [2, 0, 2]
```

This gets the output you want, though I have to say the extra zero is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The function `make_count_arr` will generate the output you are looking for in your question.

However, it is "strange" that you would not want to count "small item" (individual items) as 1 (you count it as 0).

I have provided `make_count_arr_2` which generates a count of 1 instead of 0 for individual items.

```
input_1 = ['small item', 'small item', 'large item', 'small item', 'small item']
input_2 = ['small item', 'small item', 'large item', 'small item', 'small item', 'small item', 'large item', 'large item',]

def make_count_arr(input_arr):
    count_arr = []
    c = 0

    for i in range(len(input_arr) - 1):
        if input_arr[i] == input_arr[i + 1]:
            c += 1
        else:
            count_arr.append(c + 1 if c > 0 else c)
            c = 0
    count_arr.append(c + 1 if c > 0 else c) # append last count
    return count_arr

print(make_count_arr(input_1)) # [2, 0, 2]
print(make_count_arr(input_2)) # [2, 0, 3, 2]

def make_count_arr_2(input_arr):
    count_arr = []
    c = 1
    
    for i in range(len(input_arr) - 1):
        if input_arr[i] == input_arr[i + 1]:
            c += 1
        else:
            count_arr.append(c)
            c = 1
    count_arr.append(c) # append last count
    return count_arr

print(make_count_arr_2(input_1)) # [2, 1, 2]
print(make_count_arr_2(input_2)) # [2, 1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I wanted the '0' to seperate the count for the 'small items' and if it is '1' it could get mistakened for a single 'small item'. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you can try logic something like below:

```
def count_small_items(items):
    counts = []
    count = 0

    for item in items:
        if item == "small item":
            count += 1
        elif item == "large item":
            counts.append(count)
            count = 0

    return counts

items = ['small item', 'small item', 'large item', 'small item', 'small item']
result = count_small_items(items)
print(result)  # Output: [2, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate to compare items with their predecessors. This will allow you to get the index of changes in values.  This will correspond to the end of ranges containing consecutive duplicates of a string.  These end positions can then be zipped together to form the ranges that easily convert to lengths.  Set these lengths to zero when the group doesn'T contain the desired string ('small item'):

```
L  = ['small item', 'small item', 'large item', 'small item', 'small item']

ends   = [i for i,s in enumerate(L[1:],1) if s!=L[i-1]] 
groups = [(e-s)*(L[s]=='small item') for s,e in zip([0]+ends,ends+[len(L)])]

print(groups)
[2, 0, 2]
```

I'm a bit unclear on what you expect to happen when there are multiple consecutive 'large item' values.  If you need as many zeros in the result, then you can do it the same way with different conditions:

```
L      = ['small item', 'small item', 'large item', 'large item', 
          'small item', 'small item']

ends   = [i for i,s in enumerate(L[1:],1) if s != L[i-1] or s!='small item']
groups = [(e-s)*(L[s]=='small item') for s,e in zip([0]+ends,ends+[len(L)])]

print(groups)
[2, 0, 0, 2]
```